# How can I recover the access of an account after a Graphics card installation?

Tags: permissions

After installing  the amd hd7770 videocard and installed the driver packages (which probably went wrong) I started to encounter 2 issues...

The first issue that I have is getting into the account I used to install the drivers on. After entering a correct password the screen becomes black and returns to the login screen. I was not able to fix this using Google.

The second issue is that my mouse becomes super laggy when the card is plugged in.

Please take note that the system used an onboard graphics chip before the card install.

Comment: Still not clear... what message is appearing that don't allow you to access that account?

Comment: We need more details on what's going on.  What error messages are you getting?  What's happening visually?  Those questions and others are going to need to be answered to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When I fill in the password which I know is correct, then hit enter the screen becomes black for a second and brings me back to the login screen. Only on one account.

Comment: @Kindafunny Have you tried everything from here: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)?

Comment: I cant log into tty3 for some reason.. How does this work?

Comment: If you hit Ctrl-Alt-F1, can you log in via via the command line?

Comment: @belaqua what do u mean? I got a line that says: "login :" I tried it with a username and password without succes...

Comment: @Kindafunnyb You have to insert your username and your password.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I tried that, but it gives me an invalid login message, anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Kindafunny Yes, you didn't enter the correct username and password :)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Then the username must be wrong, even tho I tried all of our usernames with password. neither of them gave me a correct login message